# What algorithm does Bitmap.smoothing use?

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3, what algorithm does Bitmap.smoothing use as default?

Bilinear, trilinear, bicubic or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses Bilinear...

See "smooth" property ...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsBitmapFill.html#smooth

Comment: That's smoothing on the `GraphicsBitmapFill` class though. Flash Player 8 was the first version that implemented [bilinear internally](http://www.kaourantin.net/2005/08/fixing-one-bug-at-time-in-flash-player.html). It is my understanding that both `BitmapData.draw()` and `GraphicsBitmapFill` are handled internally in software. However, it's unclear if smoothing on the `Bitmap` class uses bilinear as well. Bitmap interpolation might depend on hardware acceleration, just like mipmapping might be utilized if the Bitmap is of a certain size and the hardware supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Bilinear with automatic mipmaps whenever the bitmap dimension's are even. E.g. 100 will use 2 mipmap levels (100/2 = 50, 50/2 = 25), 90 will use one mipmap level (90/2 = 45).

More info: http://www.kaourantin.net/2007/06/mip-map-what.html

Demo makes it more or less obvious it's bilinear: http://www.kaourantin.net/2007/06/mip-map-what.html